# How to feed tfrecords to the networks in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I want to feed my custom data deep network using "tfrecords" in tensorflow. There are several ways to do this; using coordinator or iterator. I was mixed up with this and tried several times using book's and blog's guide. But unfortunately, none of them did work for me.
Roughly speaking assume that I have tfrecords file and a model
How can we complete the following code to feed the training process with tfrecords?

```
for tf.Session() as sess:
   # getting the images and labels
   ...

   feed_dict = {x:images, y:labels}
   loss = sess.run([optimization], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

I looked at similar questions online, but those didn't answer what I am looking for.
Here is the official link:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data

Answer (score 0):

You read TFRecord files with a tensorflow Dataset object or a TFRecordReader. I think [this article](https://www.skcript.com/svr/why-every-tensorflow-developer-should-know-about-tfrecord/) explains it well (both writing and reading TFRecord files), using TFRecordReader (I prefer Dataset, myself).

Using dataset, your pipeline is something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
filenames = [...]

def _parse_fn(x):
    feature_set = { 'image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                    'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)}
    parsed = tf.parse_single_example(x, features= feature_set )
    return parsed['image'], parsed['label']

dataset = (
    tf.data
    .TFRecordDataset(filenames)
    .map(_parse_fn) 
    .shuffle(...)
    .batch(...)
    # etc.
)

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_item = iterator.get_next() # This is a nested structure of Tensors
image, label = next_item        # Since our parse_fn returned a list of 2

... # now you build your model here, from the 'image' Tensor
    # rather than from a placeholder as you do when using feed_dict

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print sess.run([optimize])
```

The main thing to notice is that the output you will get from the Dataset or TFRecordReader is a Tensor, not a Numpy array object. Therefore, you will not use `feed_dict`, but rather build your model from the input tensor (as in, your model with extend directly from the `image` Tensor, rather than a Placeholder).